# Meteor: Slow template render blocks method return value

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm experiencing a very strange issue with Meteor whereby a single page is taking a very long time to load. I've gone down numerous routes to try and troubleshoot before identifying a cause which isn't really making sense to me.

Fundamentally I have a two-step process that collects some initial data and then inserts a couple of hundred records into the database. On the second page I then need to be able to assign users to each of the new records. I can also go back into the same page and edit the assigned users so in this second scenario the inserts have already happened - same lag.

The insert code is relatively straightforward.

#### Client Side

> setup assessment meta-data & create new assessment record + items:

```
// set updatingAssessment variable to stop subs re-loading as records are inserted
Session.set('updatingAssessment', true);

Meteor.call('insertAssessment', assessment, function(err, result) {

  if (err) { showError(err.reason); }
  var assessmentId = result.toHexString(); 

  // some code excluded to get 'statements' array

  Meteor.call('insertAssessmentItems', 
               assessmentId,
               statements, 
               function(err, result) { 
               Session.set('updatingAssessment', false);
  });
}

// hide first modal and show 2nd
Session.set("assessmentStage1", false);
Session.set("assessmentStage2", true);
```

#### Server methods

> Volume wise, we're inserting 1 assessment record and then ~200 assessment items

```
insertAssessment: function(assessment) {

this.unblock();

    return  Assessments.insert({
        <<fields>>
        }, function(err, result) { return result; });

},
insertAssessmentItems: function(assessmentId, statements) { 

    this.unblock();
        for (i = 0; i < statements.length; i++) { 

            AssessmentItems.insert({ 
                <<fields>>
            }, function(err, result) { });

        }
}
```

Initially I tried numerous SO suggestions around not refreshing subscriptions while the inserts were happening, using this.unblock() to free up DDP traffic, making queries on the slow page non-reactive, only returning the bare minimum fields, calling the inserts asynchronously, etc, etc... all of which made no difference with either the initial insert, or subsequent editing of the same records (i.e go out of the page and come back so the inserts have already happened).

After commenting out all database code and literally returning a string from the meteor method (with the same result / lag) I looked at the actual template generation code for the html page itself.

After commenting out various sections, I identified that a helper to build up a dropdown list of users (repeated for each of those ~200 records) was causing the massive spike in load time. When I commented out the dropdown creation the page load happens in <5s which is within a more acceptable range although still slower than i would like.

Two oddities with this, which I was hoping somebody could shed some light on:

1. Has anything changed recently in Meteor that would have caused a slowdown as I haven't significantly changed my code for a couple of months and it was working before, albeit still around 10 seconds to fully render the page. The page also used to be responsive when loaded, whereas now the CPU is stuck at 100% and selecting users is very laggy.
2. Why is the actual template loading blocking my server method returns? There is no doubt I need to re-write my template to be more efficient but I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why my server methods were not returning values quickly. I even analysed the DDP traffic and there was no activity while it was waiting for the template to load - no reloaded subs, no method returns, nothing.

Thanks in advance,
David